# How can I embed a controller/views within another view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two controllers with their respective views, and I would like to embed both of them into my home/index.html.erb view (home page).  I am trying to do get the CRUD actions of either of these embedded controller/views to respond without affecting the state of my home controller.  Can anyone point me to a resource or suggest an approach?  I have looked into sub-templates, but I don't think that I'll be able to get the behavior that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For "embedding" the views, this is what partials are designed for.  You can refactor the various CRUD views to leverage partials that can then also be utilized by the home/index.html.erb.

However, you would still need to setup the expected instance variables for those partials in your home_controller.  You can DRY this up through the use of filters that home and the other controllers can use...if you want to.

Finally, if you want to submit data for the individual resources from the home/index view, just point those forms at their respective controller, and redirect the user back to the home/index action when the request originates from home (if this is your desired behavior).

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Wouldn't that cause the entire home controller and the second embedded controller to fire?

Comment: For submitting data, yes.  The resource controller would process the data and then redirect to the home controller, which would mean the page would be reloaded.  You could submit as ajax via 'remote: true' as an alternate option.

Comment: Maybe ajax would be the best approach.  For simplicity at this point I suppose I was thinking more of an iframe approach, but I don't really like using iframes, but I did want to be RESTful without requiring every controller to refire when only one of them needed to.

Comment: Unless you are loading a significant amount of data with each page view (and, there are still a lot of ways to optimize for this), I think you'll find that the act of processing the resource controller#create or update + the home_controller#index will not cause any major issues.  I'd start with full page loads and then move to ajax once you get the hang of it.